# How to move sidebar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

How can I move Firefox sidebar from left to right in Firefox 3.6.x?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.6.x versions and they all have the sidebar on the left. How did you have it on the right?

Comment: ops sorry, I specified wrong. I will correct immediatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reversing this: http://www.firefoxmastery.com/firefox/move-firefox-sidebar-from-left-to-right/ ?

To move from left to right add the following to your `userChrome.css`:

```
hbox#browser { direction: rtl; }
hbox#browser > vbox { direction: ltr; }
```

Comment: He's asking for "right to left".

Comment: @Mehper: "Have you tried *reversing* this"

Comment: @Richard: I haven't tried anything. I'm just telling his question is the reverse of your answer. You may reverse your answer to fulfill what he needs.

Comment: @Mehper I just quoted the start of the answer with added emphasis because it appears that you missed a key word.

Comment: @Richard: Oh I see. Your double "this" must have made me confused ;)

Comment: @Mehper: double this was a typo. The key word was "reversed" -- it takes special action to have the side bar on the right. Therefore to move to the left reverse the move to the right.